# Coredump at sem_wait

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, ipc, fedora

I have a rather strange issue here or I am be ignorant of the way it works, but any way I have the program below that creates the semaphore properly and runs to the end for the first time. But SEGFaults at sem_wait, if the semaphore already exists.
I am running this on 64bit Fedora 17. Does this have to do anything with the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>          /* printf()                 */
#include <stdlib.h>         /* exit(), malloc(), free() */
#include <sys/types.h>      /* key_t, sem_t, pid_t      */
#include <sys/shm.h>        /* shmat(), IPC_RMID        */
#include <errno.h>          /* errno, ECHILD            */
#include <semaphore.h>      /* sem_open(), sem_destroy(), sem_wait().. */
#include <fcntl.h>          /* O_CREAT, O_EXEC          */

int
main() {


        sem_t *mysem;
        int oflag = O_CREAT | O_EXCL;
        mode_t mode = 0777;
        const char semname[] = "mysem";
        unsigned int value = 1;
        int sts;


        mysem = sem_open(semname, oflag, mode, value);
        //sem_unlink(semname);

        if(mysem == (void *)-1) {
                printf("sem_open() failed");
                exit(1);
        }

        printf("opened a semaphore successful\n");

        if(!sem_wait(mysem)) {
                /*locked */
                printf("worked\n");
        } else {
                printf("error\n");
        }
         return 0;
}
```

**Contents of /dev/shm
sem.mysem**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000332980d5f0 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.15-58.fc17.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  0x000000332980d5f0 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000000000040074a in main () at str2.c:31
```

Strange issue is that when I delete the semaphore in /dev/shm or uncomment sem_unlink it works every time. Am I doing something wrong here or do I need to run a sem_post somewhere?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `sem_open` fails it returns `SEM_FAILED`, which on my system (and probably everyone else) is the equivalent to `NULL`. Check against that instead of `-1`.

Also, if it fails then print the actual error (use e.g. [`perror()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) or [`strerror()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror)).

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault usually occurs when an attempt is made to a particular memory that CPU can not physically address. Hardware notifies OS about memory violation, the kernel (OS) in response sends a corrective action against it usually terminating it or causing a dump core. The most common cause of segmentation is **dereferencing NULL pointers**. Trying that out might help.

Comment: In my case there is one thing that I might have misunderstood. Does these 64 bit pointer values the same? 0x7f0d0b8c0000 and 0xb8c1000. I am hitting a core dump here

Comment: I think code is same to write, compile and execute fine as either a 32-bit or 64-bit pointer values. Most of the problems arise when/if you do things like assuming similarity between OS types (e.g., that a DWORD will hold a pointer -- true in 32-bit code but not in 64-bit code).

Answer (score 0):

Check man open_sem:

"If  both O_CREAT and O_EXCL are specified in oflag,then an error is returned if a semaphore with the  given  name  already exists."

It looks like your semaphore already exists. That is why your code works again after removing from /dev/shm - so it can create it again w/o error.

I'm not sure why everyone is checking for -1 return value for error when man says SEM_FAILED. Probably used to behave like open. SEM_FAILED could be defined to be anything, you should not assume its value and use the MACRO.